Why am I getting x509: Extra option when trying to generate an OpenSSL Certificate with enddate
I have a script that tries to create a certificate that expires in 10 mins...
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the number of minutes is provided, default to 10 if not
MINUTES=${1:-10}

# Variables
KEYSTORE="keystore.jks"
CERT_ALIAS="mycert"
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="changeit"
CERT_FILE="mycert.crt"
KEY_FILE="key.pem"

# Calculate the start and end dates
START_DATE=$(date -u +"%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ")
END_DATE=$(date -u -d "+$MINUTES minutes" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ")

# Generate a private key and a certificate signing request (CSR)
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout $KEY_FILE -out csr.pem -nodes -subj "/CN=localhost"

# Print the actual openssl x509 command with parameters
echo "openssl x509 -startdate $START_DATE -enddate $END_DATE -req -in csr.pem -signkey $KEY_FILE -out $CERT_FILE"

# Create a self-signed certificate with specific start and end dates
openssl x509 -startdate $START_DATE -enddate $END_DATE -req -in csr.pem -signkey $KEY_FILE -out $CERT_FILE

# Create a keystore and import the private key and certificate
openssl pkcs12 -export -in $CERT_FILE -inkey $KEY_FILE -out keystore.p12 -name $CERT_ALIAS -passout pass:$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -destkeypass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -destkeystore $KEYSTORE -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -alias $CERT_ALIAS -noprompt

# List the contents of the keystore to verify the certificate is there
keytool -list -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD

When I try to run I get something like the following
openssl x509 -startdate 20241024182455Z -enddate 20241024183455Z -req -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out mycert.crt
x509: Extra option: "20241024182455Z"
x509: Use -help for summary.

What am I missing what is wrong with the formatting for enddate?

Please follow the recommendation of x509: Use -help for summary. and check out what -enddate is actually doing. Then you'll find out that it does not do what you think and  does not have an argument - hence Extra option.
